# Assigning lines from text files to variables in batch DOS

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to run this script

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Q
SET cnt=1
ECHO Q
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%x IN ("%mytextfile.txt%") DO (
ECHO Q
    SET "PRJ_NAME=%%x"
```

i want to assign names frm text file to  variable PROJ_NAME. 
It is showing error : The syntax of this command is incorrect for 
"FOR /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%x IN ("%mytextfile.txt%") DO ( " This line
What should i do?

Comment: Remove the `%` from around the filename. The filename is not an environmental variable. You're also missing the closing `)` at the end of the `DO` block.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a `DO was unexpected at this time` error, not the error you've reported.

If you are using "Command Prompt" under windows, then the error I've mentioned would appear because the `do` clause has no terminating `)`.

If you are using real DOS, then you would get your syntax error because `for /f` is not supported under DOS, it's an extension introduced with the NT DOS emulator, nor known as "Command Prompt" but unofficially referred to as "DOS".

Comment: ) is there in actual program. i mentioned just a part of it.

Comment: We can only work with what we're shown. You've not responded about which version of "DOS" you are using.

Comment: okay...i am using command prompt. and trying to run batch file containing the code given above.

Answer (score 0):

To read a line from a text file and assign it to an environment variable use:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN (mytextfile.txt) DO (
   SET "PRJ_NAME=%%x"
   rem more commands
)
```

But this works only if the full name of the file does not contain a space character and can be therefore specified without double quotes.

But `usebackq` is needed which activates alternate parsing of double quoted strings with 1 or more space in file name:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%x IN ("my text file.txt") DO (
   SET "PRJ_NAME=%%x"
   rem more commands
)
```

Comment: tried both the things..still not working.getting same error.!

Comment: I have tried both of my suggestions before posting the answer by executing the batch file with the lines above within a command prompt window on Windows XP. The code works definitely also on newer versions of Windows. You either use a much older version of Windows (Windows 95/98) or even MS-DOS 6.0, or you have simply not tried exactly the lines I have posted. What does "mytextfile.txt" contain? And what is the real file name with path of the text file in your batch file? We can't help you if you do not show us the real batch code and real content of the text file.